# Storing a struct type reference in a variable

Tags: c#, syntax

Consider the following struct:

```
public class Definitions
{
    public struct A
    {
        public struct B
        {
            public struct C
            {
                public struct D
                {
                    public struct E
                    {
                        public static string foo = "";
                        public static string bar = "";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To refer to foo, I must use:

```
Definitions.A.B.C.D.E.foo
```

Is it possible to declare a variable like such?

```
   struct E = Definitions.A.B.C.D.E;
```

So then I can refer to it in code via:

```
E.foo
E.bar
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks

Comment: Side-note: You should not make mutable structs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`using` directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/sf0df423.aspx) to assign an alias:

```
using E = Definitions.A.B.C.D.E;
```